# What robust test should I use in order to find the correlation between two numeric vectors in R?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, correlation

I have 2 numeric vectors:

```
A = [1] 0.09112019 0.01648917 0.09959314 0.18508083 0.43382979 0.47615469 0.02759358 0.20501685 0.11723475
[10] 0.25235056 1.01360047 0.23293548 0.02809754 0.18917008 0.12235214 0.25779546 1.11210158 0.29427705
[19] 0.46955788 0.34303692 0.26483973 0.12400529 0.77529471 0.05599909 0.08754854 0.16293734 0.20511528
[28] 0.64192924 0.15366982 0.57283905 0.29810925 0.54156768 0.06472627 0.06320937 0.07423829 0.05349911
[37] 0.45069070 0.58086056 0.17868721 0.12797566 0.18313978 0.38640191 0.09796483 0.15190912

B = [1] 1586  200  315  489  200 2044  306  271  253  610  282  200  799  200  200  200  400  628  289  447  258
[22]  200  200  375  200  200  200  280  609  779  200  200  200  200  703  200  309  200  200  200  200  200
[43]  886  412
```

My hypothesis is that when `A` goes up, `B` also goes up, and I want to calculate the correlation between these two vectors and visualize it.

These two vectors are **not** normally distributed.

The scatterplot does not clearly show the correlation, it is very hard to infer anything from it. `Pearson` correlation gave me a **negative** correlation, while `Spearman` gave me a **postivie** correlation. Both of them gave very hight p-value, about 0.9, so both of them are not significant.

Hence, I cant figure it out.. I just need to find the correlation score, the right way.

This is the scatterplot:

[image]

Comment: Neither Spearman nor Pearson correlations make any assumptions about normality. You can *always* compute them provided each of the variables exhibits at least two distinct values.  As always, you are best off by first examining the scatterplot.

Comment: As you have rightly observed, the scatter plot indicates no correlation. This is confirmed by the correlation coefficient $r_{xy}$, which is 0.05: values close to zero mean no correlation. The confidence interval for $r_{xy}$ is much wider (-0.25, 0.34), but it includes zero, which also inidcates that there is no correlation.

Comment: A correlation coefficient will add very little information and does not provide a useful description of these data.  What do you really want to accomplish with your analysis?

Comment: For a better understanding of the data, I suggest plotting the transformed (e.g. log) values. There maybe more visible correlations afterward.

Comment: @whuber well these two vectors are features in wide cancer study. There is a hypothesis that when one vector goes up, it makes the seond one go up also.  We are trying to test that.

Comment: That evidently is not the case, but if you want a simple, formal test and the "one vector" is a *specific* one of the two, then perform a regression analysis.